# Manipulating scalars in a tensor (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to extract single values from a tensor and manipulate it while retaining backpropagation. My current implementation:

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation,  Input
import tensorflow as tf

input = Input(shape=(100,1), dtype='float32')
x = Dense(100)(input)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dense(5)(x)
x = Activation('tanh')(x)

start_pad = 40.0 + 5.0 * x[0] # important line
# ...

zs = K.arange(0.0, 1000, step=1.0) 
zs = K.relu( zs - start_pad )
# ...

out = zs # + ...
out = Reshape( (trace_length,1) )(out)

model = Model(inputs = input, outputs = out)
```

**However,** `start_pad` seems to be a tensor with dimensions of `x`. Running code above gives error:

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1000 and 5 for 'sub' (op: 'Sub') with input shapes: [1000], [100,5].

where `start_pad` object is `<tf.Tensor 'add_1:0' shape=(100, 5) dtype=float32>`.

I would like to have scalar like value for `start_pad` and subtract from `zs` with broadcasting. How do I achive this with Tensorflow/Keras?

Comment: At the line where `start_pad` is defined, `x` has shape `(?, 100, 5)`, because Keras adds an initial batch dimension of arbitrary size, so `x[0]` has shape `(100, 5)` (layers like `Dense` act over the last dimension). I'm not sure what value from `x` you are trying to extract, though; if you do `x[0, 0, 0]` you would get the first one, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution i found is

`x =  tf.unstack(x, axis=1)`

which returns a list of tf tensors